# How to configure Okular so that I can locate the line approximately correct, when in forwardPDF

Tags: forward-inverse-search, okular

I am using `Kile` editing my `tex` files, with `Okular` for viewing the `dvi` and `PDF` files. And I can search the source file from PDF fairly well. I have configured `Kile` as follows in order to highlight the source line when search incontrovertibly:

```
Configure Kile->Editor->Fonts & Colors->Text Area Background,
```

then I changed the default color of `Current line` into blue for example, thus I can locate the line when I clicked `Shift+Click` in `PDF` file.

But I can not do so when in `ForwardPDF`, that is from `tex` to `PDF`. What I have seen is just the page of the `PDF` file that corresponds to the source file.

How can I configure my `Okular` (or `Kile`), so that I can locate the line (for example, by highlight the line) when in `forwardPDF`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  I assume you have the `-synctex=1` option set?

Comment: Certainly I have set. Here is my configuration of Kile: XeLaTeX:  Select:  PDF Modern; Command: xelatex; Options: -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstropmode '%source'

Comment: Did you find a solution for highlighting the relevant line in okular when jumping to it in forward search?

Comment: No, I have not find a solution for locating and highlighting the relevant line in okular in forward search. And now I am using Texstudio, it works very well in Debian Wheezy, whose function of forward search and backward search is fairly wonderful.

Comment: @azhi, does your comment above mean that you've resolved the issue? Or are you still looking for answers to this question?